# 'map' object is not subscriptable in python3

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to update a module from odoo 10 to odoo12. The following code works well in odoo 10 which use python 2.7 but got map issue in python 3.x

```
def _get_search_domain(self, search, category, attrib_values):
    res =super(WebsiteSale,self)._get_search_domain(search,category,attrib_values)
    filter_list = request.httprequest.args.getlist('filter')
    domain = res
    filter_values = [map(int, v.split("-")) for v in filter_list if v]
    filters_ids = set([v[0] for v in filter_values])
    filter_set = set([v[1] for v in filter_values]) 
    if filter_values:
        filter = None
        ids = []
        list_of_d = []
        for value in filter_values:
            v = False 
            if not filter:
                filter = value[0]
                ids.append(value[1])
            elif value[0] == filter:
                ids.append(value[1])
            else:
                domain += [('filter_line_ids.value_ids', 'in', ids)]
                filter = value[0]
                ids = [value[1]]
        if filter:
            domain += [('filter_line_ids.value_ids', 'in', ids)]
    return domain
```

I got Error message:

> 'map' object is not subscriptable

I read from other helps that I should enclose the map with list. I tried replaced with the following code but still not work

```
filter_values = [list(map(int, v.split("-"))) for v in filter_list if v]
```

Could anyone help me out. Thank you!

Comment: You get the exact same error after adding the list conversion? On which line does it happen? Please post the full stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

```
filter_values = [list(map(int, v.split("-"))) for v in filter_list if v]
```

Why are casting it as List as Filter_Values is a dtype List